# Redux changing value of deep nested array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have an initial state like so:

```
const initState = {
    posts: data
}
```

now posts is something like :

```
[
  {
    "id": "",
    "text": "",
    "slug": "",
    "title": "",
    "comments": []
  },

//some more here
]
```

So what I want to do is, when dispatch is fired I want to add new comments to that specific comments array. This is how I do it:

```
 if (action.type === "ADD_COMMENT") {
        let findPost = state.posts.find(post => post.slug === action.payload.comment.postSlug);
        let index = state.posts.indexOf(findPost);
        console.log(findPost);

        return {
            ...state,
            posts: [...state.posts,
            state.posts[index].comments = [action.payload.comment, ...state.posts[index].comments]]
        }
    }
```

Even though my app works completely fine I have a problem with the redux state. Because everytime action is happened it adds new comments in to that specific array along with a new array in to state.

So in case of firing new action I do get something like this:

```
[
  {
    "id": "",
    "text": "",
    "slug": "",
    "title": "",
    "comments": ["comment here"]
  },
[
  {
    "comments": ["comment here"]
  },

//some more here
]

]
```

In each click it creates a new entry in to my state which I don't want at all. How can I make it possible that it only adds the comments in to that specific array but not as separate entry?

Comment: how do you dispatch the add comment event?

Comment: instead of using find and indexOf, you can pass the index of the item in your dispatcher.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You push the new comment in the "posts" array instead of the post's object.

You can try with a map

```
if (action.type === "ADD_COMMENT") {

 const posts = state.posts.map(post => {
       if( post.slug === action.payload.comment.postSlug){
          post.comments.unshift(action.payload.comment);
       }
       return post
    });

    return {...state, posts}
}
```

EDIT : With this solution you mutate the state, wich is not recommended
To avoid this simply copy your posts in a new variable

```
let posts = [...state.posts]
```

And then do your map.

Comment: elegant way to handle that problem

Comment: Definitely brilliant. Thanks a lot.

Comment: but this mutates the state. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37755997/why-cant-i-directly-modify-a-components-state-really

Comment: There's no point of doing ```return {...state, posts}``` since you are directly changing state.

Answer (score 2):

Pass the index of comments array in  your payload.

```
if (action.type === 'ADD_COMMENT') {
  // get the index of the item from the payload
  const index = action.payload.index;
  // create a copy
  const posts = [...state.posts];
  // add comment to comments array
  posts[index].comments.push(action.payload.comment);

  console.log(posts[index]);

  return {
    ...state,
    posts: posts,
  };
}
```

Comment: That's even better solution. Thank you for your time.